# Trying to stop users from registering duplicate names but error is not being catched

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display an error when users enter an existing username during registration. However my catch is getting bypassed and it is just being forwarded in to the second sql query where it fails because username is a primary key.

```php
$sqlx = "SELECT username FROM TBLUSERS WHERE username='".$username."'";
if( mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlx) > 0)){
    echo "Username already exists, choose a different one";
}
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO TBLUSERS (USERNAME, PASSWORD, FULLNAME, 
    street_number, street_name, suburb, state, postcode, EMAIL, 
    children_number, Children_name, Children_class, creditcard, exp_month, 
    exp_year) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$f_name','$street_no', 
    '$street_name', 
    '$suburb','$state','$postcode','$email','$no_child','$s_name', '$s_class', 
    '$credit', '$expiryMonth','$expiryYear')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Thank you for registration";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "<p>The email has been sent to</p>";
        echo "<p>$to</p>";
    }       else {
        echo "Error: Query did not succeed";
    }
}
```

So when I am registering using an existing username I want the "Username already exists, choose a different one" to come not the "Query did not succeed:.

Comment: This code should do that. The insert is probably failing for a different reason, print `mysqli_error($conn)` when the query doesn't succeed.

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL-injection, you should use prepared statements with parameters. Also, you should not store the password in plain text, it should be hashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in parentheses in this line:

```
if( mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlx) > 0)){
```

Change that to this:

```
if( mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlx)) > 0){
```

Comment: Your answer demonstrates exactly why this page can be closed as Off-topic: Typo and eventually deleted.